# Adding classes to the html markup in the custom directive's template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

When defining a custom directive, both link and compile functions get the 'element' as an argument which comes handy for adding classes to it. However, if the directive is an 'Element' directive, and the 'replace' field is set to false (as trying to avoid using this depreciated field), the element argument in the compile and link functions is the original directive's element (`<some-widget>`), and not the element in the template(`<div>`), so any added classes will be ignored by the browser.

Question: **What is the best practice to dynamically add classes to the HTML markup in the template?** (I can obviously insert classes as strings, but that feels dirrrty)

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .directive('someWidget', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: false,
            template: '<div>This is the template</div>',
            link: function (scope, element) {
                element.addClass("orange");
            }
        };
    });
```

The resulting HTML will be as follows:

```
<some-widget class="orange">
    <!-- The orange class is ignored-->
   <div>This is the template</div>
<some-widget>
```

Comment: You want to dynamically add classes based on what? Why can't you just put it in the template? Or you could just make it work with attribute restricted directives.

Comment: how can you say the classes will be ignored?

Comment: I am asking the question in general. (I could be adding classes based on what the attributes are or based on some computation in a controller I add later). My question is specifically about, adding classes to the element in the template, as in this case I cannot use element.addClasss()

Comment: yes but why is it working for me below? that OP asked in other question

Comment: @Crocodile see my answer and run console. as far as i have understood..

Comment: First of all thanks for helping. Basically in the Angular book I am reading there is a code snippet where a button is styled with a custom directive. That is: adding attributes to the HTML tag and then in the link function assign classes to the element based on these attributes. Since I learned that the replace field has been depreciated (I guess I should try avoiding it?), I started pondering how I could make it work with replace:false while keeping the code 'elegant'. The example below is highly appreciated, but it is using replace:true

Comment: no problem. yes the example is with replace true. just to demonstrate that attributes can be carried. you can use addClass() that is not that bad

Comment: What I meant to ask is how can I make it work with replace:false? (or should I not try avoiding depreciated fields?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding classes to directive when using replace set to false will add them to directive that is pretty much same as applying on div

if you set attributes on directive `<some-widget class="orange red">` that will be replaced with but attributes will remain there like `<div class="orange red">This is the template</div>`

Actually what happens is that all the attributes of the original DOM node are merged with those in the template's root node

**Working example** see console to verify

```js
 angular.module('app', [])
        .directive('someWidget', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                replace: true,
                template: '<div>This is the template</div>',
                link: function (scope, element) {
                 
                  
                }
            };
        });
```

```css
.orange{color:red;}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="app">
    <some-widget class="orange red">
       
       
    </some-widget>
      </div>
```